# How do I grey out an area outside of a polygon in MapBox for Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, mapbox, mapbox-android

I am currently using MapBox maps for Android v10.3.0. My app is written in Kotlin.

Using the [PolygonAnnotation](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/api/10.3.0/mapbox-maps-android/com.mapbox.maps.plugin.annotation.generated/-polygon-annotation/), [PolygonAnnotationManager](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/api/10.3.0/mapbox-maps-android/com.mapbox.maps.plugin.annotation.generated/-polygon-annotation-manager/), and [PolygonAnnotationOptions](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/api/10.3.0/mapbox-maps-android/com.mapbox.maps.plugin.annotation.generated/-polygon-annotation-options/) I am able to draw and shade a polygon on the map.

[Example:](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/annotations/annotations/#polygon-annotation)

```kotlin
    // Create an instance of the Annotation API and get the polygon manager.
    val annotationApi = mapView.annotations
    val polygonAnnotationManager = annotationApi.createPolygonAnnotationManager()
    // Define a list of geographic coordinates to be connected.
    val points = listOf(
      listOf(
        Point.fromLngLat(17.94, 59.25),
        Point.fromLngLat(18.18, 59.25),
        Point.fromLngLat(18.18, 59.37),
        Point.fromLngLat(17.94, 59.37)
      )
    )
    // Set options for the resulting fill layer.
    val polygonAnnotationOptions: PolygonAnnotationOptions = PolygonAnnotationOptions()
      .withPoints(points)
      // Style the polygon that will be added to the map.
      .withFillColor("#ee4e8b")
      .withFillOpacity(0.4)
    // Add the resulting polygon to the map.
    polygonAnnotationManager.create(polygonAnnotationOptions)
```

[Map with Polygon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWX64.png)

I would like to **shade the area outside of the polygon** and have the area **inside the polygon without shading**. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a polygon that occupies the whole world and add a hole inside that polygon:

```
    val points = listOf(
        listOf(
            Point.fromLngLat(-180.0, 90.0),
            Point.fromLngLat(180.0, 90.0),
            Point.fromLngLat(180.0, -90.0),
            Point.fromLngLat(-180.0, -90.0),
            Point.fromLngLat(-180.0, 90.0)
        ),
        listOf(
            Point.fromLngLat(17.94, 59.25),
            Point.fromLngLat(18.18, 59.25),
            Point.fromLngLat(18.18, 59.37),
            Point.fromLngLat(17.94, 59.37),
            Point.fromLngLat(17.94, 59.25)
        )
    )
```

Comment: Thank you. That is a very useful tactic.